# Can't run command from command line: ffmpeg doesn't convert file

Tags: java, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an audio from one format to another: `test.mpga` into `test.ogg` using `ffmpeg` library. I have this directory structure:

```
TestConvert
  ffmpeg
    ffmpeg.exe
    ffplay.exe
    ffprobe.exe
  audio
    test.mpga
  src
    main
      java
        somepackage
          utils
            Utils  <--- CmdTest run from here
```

This is my code:

```
class CmdTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String path = "C:\\...\\TestConvert";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( path + "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -i " + path + "\\audio\\test.mpga " + path + "\\audio\\test.ogg");
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) { break; }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I run it, it prints nothing and exits with exit code `0`. `test.ogg` doesn't seem to appear anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

I was also wondering if it's possible to take that file from resources folder?

**EDIT**: I tried to use `ProcessBuilder`, but it still doesn't create a `test.ogg` file and prints something unreadable:

```
"C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
```

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
   "cmd.exe", "/c", path +
   "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -i " + path +
   "/audio/test.mpga" + path + "/audio/test.ogg");
 builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
 Process p = builder.start();
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line;
 while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line == null) { break; }
          System.out.println(line);
    }
```

At the same time, making it `cd` to the directory with the `ffmpeg.exe` and, after putting `test.mpga` inside it, running this works:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
       "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + path + "\\ffmpeg &&" +
       "ffmpeg -i test.mpga test.ogg");
```

Potentially, I'd like it all to work inside a jar, so I'd really like to be able to get it to take the .exe and .mpga from the resources.

**EDIT**:

This didn't work either:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
   path + "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe",
   "ffmpeg -i " + path + "/audio/test.mpga " + path + "/audio/test.ogg");
```

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime`, it will, for one, handle spaces in the paths better.  Also, make sure you either redirect the system error output or are reading it as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wouldn't I have to specify `cmd.exe` when using the builder? I'd like the same code to work both on Windows and Linux

Comment: No - since it's not a "terminal command" - it's an executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to use ProcessBuilder, but it still doesn't create a test.ogg file

Ok, you need to take some more time reading the JavaDocs in a little more detail.

Both `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.exec` provide you the ability to pass the command and parameters as seperate elements.

This eliminates issues with "spaces" in the command (or parameters) and you won't need to escape these issues.

Instead of ...

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
   "cmd.exe", "/c", path +
   "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -i " + path +
   "/audio/test.mpga" + path + "/audio/test.ogg");
```

You might use something more like...

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command(path + "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe",
        "-i",
        path + "/audio/test.mpga",             
        path + "/audio/test.ogg");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

You could also use `builder.directory(new File(path));` to change the working directory, which might make it easier to build the command

Comment: `path,             
        "/audio/test.mpga" + path + "/audio/test.ogg");` I assume you meant `path +             
        "/audio/test.mpga" + path + "/audio/test.ogg");`? With the former I get `C:\...\TestConvert: Permission denied`, with the later `C:\...\TestConvert/audio/test.mpga C:\..\TestConvert/audio/test.ogg: Invalid argument`

Comment: I was having fun parsing your string